# Is gnupg's tsign compatible with S/MIME

Tags: gnupg, smime, web-of-trust

GnuPG supports creating trust signatures using the `tsign` sub-command. (The documentation is not really verbose about this.) By using this option it is possible to create a certificate hierarchy similar to the CA-hierarchy in S/MIME.

Is it possible to convert GnuPG trust signatures to S/MIME signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GnuPG implements the OpenPGP specification, which is not compatible to X.509 and S/MIME. Not only the format in which keys, certifications, signatures and messages are stored are different and OpenPGP implements a variety of the CFB mode for encryption, also the trust model differs heavily (web of trust/network in the case of OpenPGP, and a hierarchical trust system for X.509): while you can map the X.509 certificate hierarchy into an OpenPGP trust network, the other way is not generally possible (for example, OpenPGP allows loops, which cannot be mapped to a tree). Furthermore, the metadata stored in keys is different.

While you could theoretically export the eg. RSA primes and convert a key from one format into the other, those would still not be compatible. Similarly, there is no way to convert certificates from one system to the other in a compatible way. An example why this will not work out is that the certificate is issued on a hash sum of the key, which is not reversible and calculated on different input for each of the systems.